# How to get back all the rows which are updated in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mariadb

I hope someone can help me. I want to get back all the rows which are updated and i found something in this forum. But now i created a 'PROCEDURE' and wanted to combine the Update statement with the needed other statements as Strings and execute the String with the 'PREPARE' statement. But because of some reasons this doesn't work. The Query (not as String) itself works.

Can someone help me ?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateAndGetUpdatedRows$$

CREATE PROCEDURE updateAndGetUpdatedRows (IN query varchar(255))
  BEGIN
    SET @buffer = CONCAT_WS(' ','SET @uids := null;',query,'AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(",", ID, @uids) );','SELECT @uids;');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @buffer;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END$$

DELIMITER ;

call updateAndGetUpdatedRows('UPDATE expensesData SET value = 22 WHERE ID = 64');
```

System:

innodb_version:     5.5.55-MariaDB-38.8
protocol_version:   10
slave_type_conversions
version:    5.5.57-MariaDB
version_comment:    MariaDB Server
version_compile_machine:    x86_64
version_compile_os:     Linux

Comment: you can only pass 1 statement to sql.

Comment: Thanks it help me :-) I changed it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because of P.Salmon i figured it out. Following the solution:

DELIMITER $$

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateAndGetUpdatedRows$$

CREATE PROCEDURE updateAndGetUpdatedRows (IN query varchar(255))
  BEGIN
    SET @uids := null;
    SET @buffer = CONCAT_WS(' ',query,'AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(",", ID, @uids) );');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @buffer;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    SELECT @uids;

  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```